# I have little problem installing bcrypt to my package.json

Tags: javascript, express, npm, bcrypt

---

I have started my project and I have started installing packages but suddenly I got an error and that error comes when I try to install a bcrypt.

---

1. first I try to install bcrypt.

   ```
   npm install bcrypt
   ```
2. I got an error.

   ```
   > bcrypt@3.0.7 install C:\Users\Abdulsalam\application\clothes_store\node_modules\bcrypt
   > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

   node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
   node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases   /download/v3.0.7/bcrypt_lib-v3.0.7-node-v64-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz 
   node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@3.0.7 and node@10.15.3 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
   gyp ERR! configure error 
   gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Abdulsalam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
   gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
   gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
   gyp ERR! stack                                ^
   gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
   gyp ERR! stack 
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
   gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
   gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
   gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\Abdulsalam\\application\\clothes_store\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding\\bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\Abdulsalam\\application\\clothes_store\\node_modules\\bcrypt\\lib\\binding" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v64"
   gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Abdulsalam\application\clothes_store\node_modules\bcrypt
   gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
   gyp ERR! not ok 
   node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Abdulsalam\application\clothes_store\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\Abdulsalam\application\clothes_store\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Abdulsalam\application\clothes_store\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
   node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
   node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Abdulsalam\\application\\clothes_store\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
   node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Abdulsalam\application\clothes_store\node_modules\bcrypt
   node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
   node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
   node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
   Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Abdulsalam\application\clothes_store\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=C:\Users\Abdulsalam\application\clothes_store\node_modules    \bcrypt\lib\binding --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
   npm WARN clothes_store@1.0.0 No description
   npm WARN clothes_store@1.0.0 No repository field.
   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted        {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.7 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.7 install script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Abdulsalam\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-09T18_07_53_927Z-debug.log
   ```

---

Sorry It's a long error but I hope someone helps me because I have to finish this project very quickly
and I haven't started yet.

Comment: are you using npm to install packages to a python project ? Cause I'm seeing python code inside your error stack

Comment: no, I have created a new one, I just have app.js

Answer (score 2):

If you're using windows, you need to use bcryptjs via:

```
npm install --save bcryptjs
```

Comment: i have used bcrypt for a while and I have no problem in windows

Comment: hmm strange, i had an issue installing bcrypt with npm, but it worked fine with bcryptjs (it's the same package btw)

Comment: They are the same package but use different binaries for install. bcryptjs works for windows 10, where as bcrypt has some reported issues

Answer (score 0):

You are facing some of the error described inside the `bcrypt` package. I advice you to go to [their npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) and read through the description.

They have a paragraph where they describe:

IF you have an error like this:

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.2/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.2-node-v48-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

make sure you have the appropriate dependencies installed and configured for your platform. You can find installation instructions for the dependencies for some common platforms in [this page](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions).

So I just advice you to go to their page and follow the instructions..